# .htaccess DirectoryIndex page links broken

Tags: .htaccess, directoryindex

In my `.htaccess` file the `DirectoryIndex` is set to `/page/main/home.html`

Therefore when I go to `www.thisexample.com` the browser address bar shows `www.thisexample.com` while actually loading `www.thisexample.com/page/main/home.html`. This is all great but now onto the problem:

Any `.html` pages that are linked to from `home.html` can't be found. In other words when I click on the info link (on the home page) it looks for `www.thisexample.com/info.html` (non-existant) instead of showing `www.thisexample.com/info.html` in the browser address bar but actually loading `www.thisexample.com/page/main/info.html` (the ultimate goal here).

It might help to add that `home.html` has no issue finding it's css stylesheet through a relative path, just can't find the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DirectoryIndex` is supposed to be the name of default **file** name like `index.html` or `index.php` for ex:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

If you want to load all the `.html` files from `/page/main` then have these rewrite rules:

```
DirectoryIndex home.html

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^page/main/ page/main%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Also start using absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: I added `RewriteRule !^page/main/ /page/main%{REQUEST_URI} [L]` to the `.htaccess` file in `/public_html`. I still have `DirectoryIndex /page/main/home.html` there, otherwise it just brings me to the parent directory. Links still not working. Can you clarify the implementation?

Comment: In case you find css, js, images links broken try `<base href="/" />` on top of your HTML page.

Comment: You need to have just `DirectoryIndex home.html`

Comment: .htaccess now has `RewriteRule !^page/main/ /page/main%{REQUEST_URI} [L]` and `DirectoryIndex home.html` . Unfortunately now it just brings me to the parent directory. css and js is fine. They are linked as `"/../../css/stylesheet.css"`. No problem there. Any ideas on the linking?

Comment: See edited code above. Specifically you needed `RewriteEngine On` line at the top.

Comment: Yes I added `RewriteEngine On` to the top. Still being brought to the parent directory. Ideas?

Comment: Here is the entire `.htaccess` file :`# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
RewriteBase /

DirectoryIndex home.html

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]]
RewriteRule !^page/main/ /page/main%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]`

Comment: ok can you try loading `www.thisexample.com/info.html` URL now

Comment: also for `www.thisexample.com` instead of getting brought to parent directory now i just get 404 error page which perhaps shows it is trying to find `home.html`

Comment: But when you load `http://www.thisexample.com/page/main/info.html` it loads up fine?

Comment: Actually no, that link also produces a 404 error now. I know the file is there however, just checked. Maybe th rewrite rules are wrong?

Comment: That is strange, are your sure this .htaccess is in DOCUMENT_ROOT of your site?

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.